# Angular 4 aux routing

Tags: angular

So, i want clear url after aux routing from

```
http://localhost:4200/(popup:login)
```

to

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

and use

```
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: null } }]"
```

but this stuff don't help me, and don't change url to

```
 http://localhost:4200/
```

I use Angular 4.1.3 CLI
 routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch:'full', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'login', outlet:'popup', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'register', outlet:'popup', component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

create routing

```
[routerLink]="[{outlets: {popup: ['login']}}]"
```

Comment: You mentioned what it doesn't do. What does it do? This should clear the outlet as you have defined: `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: null } }]"`

Comment: @overLoader [Location Back](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#find-the-way-back)